# Django Query Multiple Models with ForeignKey and ManyToMany Filed with Count

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have 3 DB tables (models) that I'm trying to use Django ORM query to get count of restaurants based on cuisine type in every city.

**Models:**

```
RESTAURANT
name ..
city = models.ForeignKey('City') 
cuisine_types = models.ManyToManyField('Cuisinetype')

CITY
name ..

CUISINETYPE
name ..
```

If I was using raw SQL query, something like this would give me the desired results:

```
SELECT 
  city.`name` AS city,
  cuisinetype.`cuisine`,
  COUNT(
    restaurant_cuisine_types.`cuisinetype_id`
  ) AS total 
FROM
  restaurant_cuisine_types 
  JOIN cuisinetype 
    ON restaurant_cuisine_types.`cuisinetype_id` = cuisinetype.`id` 
  JOIN restaurant 
    ON restaurant_cuisine_types.`restaurant_id` = restaurant.`id` 
  JOIN city 
    ON restaurant.`city_id` = city.`id` 
GROUP BY cuisinetype_id,
  city.name 
ORDER BY city,
  cuisine 
LIMIT 0, 1000;
```

RESULTS

```
city    cuisine total
Albuquerque American    5
Albuquerque French  1
Albuquerque Italian 1
Albuquerque Southwest   2
Albuquerque Steak   2
Atlanta American    6
Atlanta Asian   1
Atlanta Continental 2
Atlanta Fusion  1
Atlanta International   1
Atlanta Italian 1
...
```

So what is the Django way to get these results?